# Cakephp get value from dropdownlist

Tags: cakephp, drop-down-menu

This is the code in my view:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Chart');
echo $this->Form->input('username',
        array('label'=>('Usernames List'),
        'empty'=>('Select username'),
        'options'=>$usernames, 'selected'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('month',
        array('label'=>('Month'),
        'empty'=>('Select month'),
        'options'=>$months, 'selected'=>false));?>
echo $this->Form->input('year',
        array('label'=>('Year'),
        'empty'=>(date('Y')),
        'options' => $years, 'selected'=>false));
echo $this->Form->end('Create Chart');
```

And in my controller I try to get the values from the above dropdownlists, this is my code:

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
            $username = $this->data['Chart']['username'];
            $month = $this->data['Chart']['month'];
                        $year = $this->data['Chart']['year'];
        }
```

But what I get in $username, $month and $year variables is the index of the element in the dropdownlist, instead of the value. For example if I select 2012 in Year droddownlist I get '0', but what I need is '2012'.

How can I get the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array_combine ([doc here](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php))

```
$usernames = array_combine($usernames, $usernames);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Give like this

```
$username = array('name1'=>'Name1','name2'=>'Name2'...);
```